# Viewing a page in Chrome, how to control content width independently of window width?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

I often view webpages with sidebars on one or both sides of the main text. (E.g. the sidebar with related questions to the right of this question.) Sometimes, the webpage designer makes the sidebars a fixed width, but fails to specify a fixed or minimum width for the main text. When I reduce the width of the browser window, the width of the main text gets squeezed down to only a few words per line.

I would like to force Chrome to render the webpage at some arbitrary width independent of the window width. Then I could reduce the window width as much as I want without squeezing the main text. Because the webpage would be wider than the window, I would need to scroll horizontally to see everything, but usually I don't care about seeing the sidebars anyway. How can I achieve this? Any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly hack that may be more trouble than it is worth, but you can do a print preview and choose the "Simplify page" option; if the web site is coded well semantically, all the junk in the side bars will disappear.

Comment: Thanks. Although looking at a print preview isn't really a viable solution, this did get me thinking about some different ways to tackle the problem. If I could apply the same "simplify page" logic to the normal webpage view (not a print preview) it would resolve the issue. Some extensions that look promising: Readability, Stylish, or Tampermonkey.

Comment: Tampermonkey is extremely powerful.